# MySQL query showing rows that should be omited

Tags: mysql, sql

So I don't know what I'm missing here?  When I run this query I'm getting rows with a license_id that are not 3767 along with the correct rows that have 3767.  If I say "where users_licenses.license_id = 3767" I should only receive records with a license_id of 3767 correct?

```
select * from users 
join users_licenses on users_licenses.user_id = users.id 
join groups on groups.id = users.group_id
WHERE  users_licenses.license_id = 3767 and groups.id = 6325 or groups.id = 6343
```

Now it's something with the or statement because when it's just one group ID it works.  But still why should the or in the second where clause matter?  I should still only receive rows with a license_id of 3767

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parentheses, until you get used to how `and` and `or` work.
Your `where` clause is parsed as:

```
WHERE (users_licenses.license_id = 3767 and groups.id = 6325) or
      groups.id = 6343
```

which does not seem to be your intention.

However, you can simplify your filtering in this case using `in`:

```
where users_licenses.license_id = 3767 and groups.id in (6325, 6343)
```

Comment: sorry man went on lunch break before the time it made me wait to accept answer